# asp Server.Transfer put parameter

Tags: asp-classic, server.transfer

i googled many samples, all show such code

```
Server.Transfer("/default.asp?p=news")
```

but i get error -An invalid character was specified in the Path parameter for the MapPath method.

can you help me?

Comment: You could use response.redirect, depending on what you are doing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Server.Transfer method actually **doesn't** support any kind of querystring specified in the path. You can try to store the query parameter in a **session value** instead.

Some discussions: 
http://classicasp.aspfaq.com/general/why-won-t-querystring-values-work-with-server-execute/server-transfer.html

Comment: can it be solved without session? may be iis 7 or something else?

Comment: session is a workaround. it doesn't actually fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The following might be a work around to using server.transfer or response.redirect.

```
Response.Write "<script language=javascript>window.location.href = '/default.asp?p=news';</script>"
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have to include your querystring on the page that does the server transfer.

Ie:

**page.asp?p=news** would include:

```
  Server.Transfer("default.asp")
```

**default.asp** would include:

```
  sParam = Request("p") '<-- Your querystring value from page.asp
```

This should work, or if your app isn't flexible to do this, you can use `Session` to pass the value. It says here which methods are allowed for passing variables using `Server.Transfer`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525800%28v=vs.90%29.aspx